# data exchange format ocaml to python numpy or pandas

Tags: python, numpy, ocaml, export-to-csv, hdf5

I'm generating time series data in ocaml which are basically long lists of floats, from a few kB to hundreds of MB. I would like to read, analyze and plot them using the python numpy and pandas libraries. Right now, i'm thinking of writing them to csv files.

A binary format would probably be more efficient? I'd use HDF5 in a heartbeat but Ocaml does not have a binding. Is there a good binary exchange format that is usable easily from both sides? Is writing a file the best option, or is there a better protocol for data exchange? Potentially even something that can be updated on-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to mention, that there're actually bindings for HDF-5 for OCaml. But, when I was faced with the same problem I didn't find one that suits my purposes and is mature enough. So I wouldn't suggest you to use it, but who knows, maybe today there is something more descent.

So, to my experience the best way to store numeric data in OCaml is Bigarrays. They are actually wrappers around the C-pointer, that can be allocated outside of OCaml runtime. They also can be a memory mapped regions. So, for me this is the most efficient way to share data between different processes (potentially written in different languages). You can share data using memory mapping with OCaml, Python, Matlab or whatever with very little pain, especially if you're not trying to modify it from different processes simultaneously.

Other approaches, is to use MPI, ZMQ or bare sockets. I would prefer the latter for the only reason that the former doesn't support bigarrays. Also, I would suggest you to look for capn'proto, it is also very efficient, and have bindings for OCaml and Python, and for your particular use case, can work very fine.

Comment: Really, there is HDF5? I only found the library hdf which is HDF4. Anyway, could you give / point me to a minimal code example of how to share a Bigarray using memory mapping, if only the Ocaml side writes?

Comment: Specifically, for memory mapping, i would need to write the Bigarray to a file and then read it using numpy.memmap, correct? And without using a file, how do I pass the memory to python via a socket or pipe?

Comment: here is the link for HDF5 https://bitbucket.org/vlayceh/hdf5-ocaml. You shouldn't _write_ array to memap, you should memmap your data to the file object, so that no actual memory disk operations are involved. In memory mapping you're using files only as names, i.e., the serve you as a way of passing addresses to another process.  For a code example see at [save_to_file](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/src/server/mmap_server.ml#L37) function

Comment: With pipe or socket you just write data to the file descriptor. In addendum to the previous example, you can start with data that is already mapped, so that you don't need to copy it to shared buffer.

Comment: thanks, i tried to replicate the example with only standard lib functions and almost got it to work. in principle Bigarray.map_to_file should also work, right?

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is whether there is disk space allocated for the memmapped file but it's also fully in memory. Reading the docs it seems like that. It doesn't really matter, there is certainly enough disk space but your comment suggested otherwise.

Comment: yes, `Bigarray.map_to_file` is fine, everything else is implemented on top of it. But anyway, when I was using python to analyze OCaml's output I've just used pipes (with `popen`) and dumped data to python. There was hundred megs of data, and everything works pretty fine. So maybe using memap just for debugging purposes is overkill...